# Replace an existing android app with a new one

Tags: android

I have recently launched an app on Google Play, and am trying to launch an update for it. However, due to some reasons, my KeyStore has been corrupted, and hence google is not allowing me to release the update for the same application.

Is there  away using which I can release a new app in the market, and update the existing users about the new app so that they can replace the existing app with the new one?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way, you'd have to upload it as another package and take down the other one(or not, just put it in description hoping they'd look)

Answer (score 0):

**WHEN CAN YOU UPDATE THE APP ON GOOGLE PLAY STORE?**

You can update the version of your android application on android market when you have the keystore file which was signed to the current version of your android application which is already on your market. If your keystore file is lost or missed by some reason, I am sorry to say but you can do nothing further more to update your version to android market..

**NOW WHAT TO DO IF YOU DNOT HAVE KEYSTORE?**

You can make same application with the different package name and signed with the new keystore file and upload a new fresh application on the google play market and make sure next time this keystore file not going to loss for more update of the application..

Hope it will work for you..!!!